# React-native / Expo: Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object

Tags: reactjs, expo, native

I am new to react native. I was able to connect my app to Expo go on my android device successfully, but it keeps showing "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean abi44_0_0.host.exp.expenent.modules.api.reanimated.layoutReanimation.ReaLayoutAnimation.isLayoutAnimationEnabled()' on a null object reference". It does not show anything else, even after reloading severally. [Here is how it is displayed on my device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXWPX.png)

[Here is how it is displayed on my android device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARI0k.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V468N.png)

Although I was able to open the app on a web browser on my computer. I don't know what could have gone wrong.

here is my code.

```js
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar'
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native'
//App.js File
export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
      <StatusBar style='auto' />
    </View>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
})
```